# Can i use QWSServer in qt5?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.11

I am porting old Qt4.8 code to Qt5.11.

The following code is written in Qt4.8. ("main.cpp")

This code was added to show the black background and to make the cursor invisible at program started.

```
QWSServer::setBackground(QBrush(Qt::black));
QWSServer::setCursorVisible( false );
```

I know that "QWSServer" can not use in Qt5.

Is there a any class that can be used instead of "QWSServer"?

OR, Is there a way to achieve the same effect as "QWSServer"?

Comment: Use QPA: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Platform_Abstraction

Comment: Relevant: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74931

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will use wpa.

Comment: You're welcome! It's QPA and it's the official replacement for QWS. Good luck!